# Why is pyscripter displaying an error message when I try to import modules that I have already downloaded?

Tags: python, windows, module, pyscripter

I have used windows and cmd to download modules, for python version 3.9, such as pydrive, easygui etc however when I try to import them in pyscripter I recieve an error message displaying:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<module2>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easgui'`.

I am trying to complete this geeks for geeks tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collecting-data-with-google-forms-and-pandas/
and need to download several modules. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to answer on your question. I have check the error message. Also, I think you want to install `easygui` module. But in error message, its spell is `easgui`.

Please install `easygui` module and import it correctly.

For install, please run below instruction on cmd.

```
pip install easygui
```

and for import, please write code as below.

```
import easygui
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.